# For any two elements $a, b$ in a field of characteristic $p$, $(a+b)^{p^k} = a^{p^k} +b^{p^k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let p be a prime. Show that for any two elements $a, b$ in a field of characteristic $p$, $(a+b)^{p^k} = a^{p^k} +b^{p^k}$ for any $k \geq 0$

My intuition tells me that I should proceed by saying that $p^k$ is the order of the field and use that to prove the result, but i'm not sure that is true.

Comment: Hint: the binomial theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#Prime_characteristic

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial theorem and induction:  since $x^{n^k}$ is just $x$ raised to the $n$ a total of $k$ times, you see that it is enough to show that $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p\mod p$. And this follows from the binomial theorem and the fact that $p \big| {p\choose k}$ when $1\le k\le p-1$.